# Iphone ActivityIndicator at Middle of NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

Is It Possible to put Activityindicator at  middle of the NavigationBar ??

I am working with IOS 5.0, I can put it  as rightbarbutton but i dont know how to put it at middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the view used for the text with:

```
    self.navigationItem.titleView = myActivityIndicatorViewInstance;
```

Setting the size etc correctly can be a pain. Note this code should be in an UIViewController subclass, e.g. in the viewDidLoad method.